# script to crop canvas size to visable image size in transparent png file

Tags: linux, png, crop, transparent

I have a collection of transparent .png files.
They are all a standard canvas size of 220x132 but the image might only be for example 150x40 with the rest of the image being transparent background..

Is there a way to crop the canvas size to the actual visible image area using linux script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagick is a powerful framework for doing all kinds of image editing from the command line. Cropping is a part of it.

See the documentation here: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/
Of special interest for you might be the `trim` command: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#trim

However, it might very well be, that a simple `repage` does the job. This depends on how your PNG image is built: PNGs can contain layer boundary information. `trim` will be perfectly fine for you, but `repage` might be faster when dealing with a huge amount of images.

When ImageMagick is installed, try these commands: `identify`, `display`, `convert`, `mogrify` on your images.

Comment: mogrify did the job pervectly but for some reason it added an extra `.` to the results..  I used this line:  `mogrify -path /tmp/cropped -format .png -trim *.png` but all the results are `????..png` rather than `????.png`

Comment: Please ignore, sorted now.. I had `-format .png` instead of `-format png`